# Rotating the editable div inside foreignObject is disappearing text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a foreignObject and inside it an editable div, which I want to rotate from its center to make it editable y'axis of graph. Now the problem is that when I have rotated it to -90deg angle then most of it disappear. I also want that when someone type something in the editable div then it should also show. please take a look at my code

```html
<foreignObject class="frobj" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<div contenteditable="true" style="font-size: 30px; transform: rotate(-90deg); transform-origin: left;">
Intensity (a.u.)
</div>
</foreignObject>
```

Comment: as you are rotating this to -90deg so its obvious that it would go out side of view, with rotate use translateX(-25%) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are rotating this to -90deg so its obvious that it would go out side of view, with rotate use translateX(-25%) as well to pull it in view

```html
<foreignObject class="frobj" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<div contenteditable="true" style="font-size: 30px; transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-25%); transform-origin: left;">
Intensity (a.u.)
</div>
</foreignObject>
```